# Check if any comma seperated value exists inside loop values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I get some values from an old db of a client as such:

```
$query = "SELECT rowid,source FROM `".$table."`";
$result = mysql_query($query);$temp=0;$p = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {$p[$temp] = $row;$temp++;}
```

and then I loop through the values as such:

```
// loop through all possible values
foreach ($p as $obj) {

}
```

Inside the foreach loop I will print `<option>` element and I want to determine the `<option selected/>` elements. The selected elements could be more than 1, since its a **multiselect** form.

First thing I check whether a `$selected` value equals to rowid.

```
// check if exists equals to rowid
if ($obj["rowid"] == $selected){
   $return .= '<option value="'.$obj["rowid"].'" selected>'.$obj["source"].'</option>';
}else{
   $return .= '<option value="'.$obj["rowid"].'">'.$obj["source"].'</option>';                 
}
```

This works just find if `$selected = "1"` (or any single digit)

My problem and my question comes if `$selected = "3,4"`. Then I need to loop through the values and **separate** the comma-separated values inside foreach ?

Here is my complete code:

```
$selected = "3,4";
$query = "SELECT rowid,source FROM `" . $table . "`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$temp = 0;
$p = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $p[$temp] = $row;
    $temp++;
}

// loop through all possible values
foreach($p as $obj) {
    // check if exists equals to rowid
    if ($obj["rowid"] == $selected) {
        $return.= '<option value="' . $obj["rowid"] . '" selected>' . $obj["source"] . '</option>';
    }
    else {

        // check if default exists with comma separated values
        if (!empty($default) && strpos($selected, ',') !== false) {
            $arr_values = explode(',', $selected);

            // loop through comma-separated values to get the selected items
            foreach($arr_values as $selected) {
                if ($obj["rowid"] == $default) {
                    $return.= '<option value="' . $obj["rowid"] . '" selected>' . $obj["source"] . '</option>';
                }
            }

            // $return .= '<option value="'.$obj["rowid"].'">'.$obj["source"].'</option>';
        }
        else {
            $return.= '<option value="' . $obj["rowid"] . '">' . $obj["source"] . '</option>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) + [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions combination to check if `rowid` exists in `selected` string

```
if (in_array ($obj["rowid"], explode(",",$selected))){
      $return .= '<option value="'.$obj["rowid"].'" selected>'.$obj["source"].'</option>';
}else{
      $return .= '<option   value="'.$obj["rowid"].'">'.$obj["source"].'</option>';                 
}
```

**Explanation:** E.G. if `$selected = "3,4"` then `explode(",",$selected)` return you `array(3,4)` and `in_array` check if `$obj["rowid"]`' exists in that array so it mean you will have in you output multiple `<options` with attribute `selected` set

Comment: And I dont know why I haven't thought about this. Thank you

Comment: I see your suggestion about to edit answer with additional check `if( $obj["rowid"] == $selected || ...` but it actually useless because  `in_array ($obj["rowid"], explode(",",$selected))` will handle also case when `$selected` equal to just singe number `($selected="3")`